# Fix the regex code in .htaccess for beautifying this url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, duplicates

my current regex code to beautify a url (www.abc.com/user.php?url="rio") in .htaccess file is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} user
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ user.php?url=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ user.php?url=$2
```

It works fine and the page url is beautified to :

```
www.abc.com/user/rio
```

but there is a problem now, Now even if I change url like in following ways:

```
www.abc.com/user/user/user/rio
www.abc.com/user///rio
www.abc.com/user/abc/rio
```

These links work same way, and that is making content duplication.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# remove multiple slashes
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]

# handles /user/something
RewriteRule ^user/([\w-]+)/?$ user.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

`Options -MultiViews` is required to turn off content negotiation feature.